# remove duplicate values in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Hello Developers I have to print a report in my application. I am using codeigniter. I have a table like this in my database.

```
Report Detail
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   Test_ID      Description    Description_Group       Test_Name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    117          value 1         group 1                Test 1
2    117          value 2         group 1                Test 1
3     4           another 1       group 2                Test 2
4     4           another 2       group 2                Test 2
5     4           another 3       group 2                Test 2
```

I want to print like this

```
 desired print format
    -----------------------------------------------
    Description
    -----------------------------------------------
    **Test 1**
    group 1
      value 1
      value 2

   **Test 2**
   group 2
     another 1
     another 2
     another 3
```

Here is my Model Codel

```
public function print_report($Patient_ID, $ID)
{

    $query = $this->db->query('select a.ID, a.Description, a.Description_Group, a.Normal_Range, a.Measure_Unit,
                               b.Result_Value
                               from tbltestdefault a
                               inner join tblreportdetail b on a.ID = b.Test_Default_ID
                               where b.Patient_ID = '.$Patient_ID.' and b.Patient_Test_ID  = '.$ID.'');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function print_report($ID, $Patient_ID, $Test_ID)
{
    $data['patient'] = $this->Report_Model->getPatientinfo($Patient_ID);
    $data['testname'] = $this->Report_Model->gettestnameonly($Test_ID);
    $data['tests'] = $this->Report_Model->print_report($Patient_ID, $ID);
    $this->load->view('report_view', $data);
}
```

and a view to display data

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> <h4>Description</h4>
                </th>
                <th> <h4>Result</h4>
                </th>
                <th> <h4>Units</h4>
                </th>
                <th> <h4>Normal Value</h4>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($tests as $t): ?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $t['Description_Group']; ?>
                    <?php echo $t['Description']; ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $t['Result_Value']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['Measure_Unit']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['Normal_Range']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: okay, cool. What have you tried to make that happen so far? (we're not going to write your code for you, we're only here to help you figure out why the code **you** tried isn't working)

Comment: I just get all data from table with foreach and display as it is..

Comment: don't tell me that's what you're doing, show us the code you've used, what that yielded, and why you feel that wasn't what you wanted. Edited into your post (not answered as a comment)

Comment: yeah sure..have a look now please

Comment: that's pretty good additional information; still missing bit is what it's generating right now that makes you feel like it's doing the wrong thing. Is it showing the right data, formatted wrong? Or is it showing the wrong data entirely?

Comment: its showing the right data but I want to show in right format. I explain in my post

Comment: if the data is right, but the formatting is wrong, then one thing to note is that the whole SQL part of your question doesn't matter, and it's a question about "I have this structured data: ..., and I want to format it to look like this: ... but instead using this code, ..., it looks like this: ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man, i think you are taking this site for granted.. i already provided you the main logic.you just need to expand it depending on your additional needs.. btw here's the expanded logic

```
<?php
$get_title = '';
$get_subtitle = '';
foreach($tests as $t)
{
    //if start of new test name
    if($get_title != $t['Test_Name'])
    {
        echo $t['Test_Name'];

        //if start of new desc group
        if($get_subtitle != $t['Description_Group'])
        {
            echo $t['Description_Group'];
            echo $t['description'];
            $get_subtitle = $t['Description_Group'];
        }
        //if same desc with previous
        elseif($get_subtitle == $t['Description_Group'])
        {
            echo $t['description'];
        }
        $get_title = $t['Test_Name'];
    }
    //if same title with previous
    elseif($get_title == $t['Test_Name'])
    {
        //if start of new desc group
        if($get_subtitle != $t['Description_Group'])
        {
            echo $t['Description_Group'];
            echo $t['description'];
            $get_subtitle = $t['Description_Group'];
        }
        //if same desc with previous
        elseif($get_subtitle == $t['Description_Group'])
        {
            echo $t['description'];
        }
    }
}
```

add this at the last part of your sql query
   ORDER BY Test_Name ASC, Description_Group ASC, Description ASC
not sure if this would work, because i haven't tried it.. hit me with some comments if something went wrong..cheers

Comment: @ShafatAhmad you can accept my answer if that satisfies you.. thanks :D

Comment: Hello @Kelvin Barsana are you there?